# How do I specify an installation location for Xcode 4.1 from the Mac App Store?

Tags: xcode4, mac-app-store

I just installed Lion, and downloaded Xcode 4.1 from the Mac App Store.  I like having my Xcodes installed in `/Developer` directories that have their Xcode versions appended (e.g. `/Developer-xcode3.2.6`).  Downloading Xcode 4.1 from the Mac App Store just gives me an installer app, which does not allow me to specify an installation location, as Xcode installers did in the past.  When I ran the installer, it asked me to move old Xcode 3 installs out of `/Developer`, so is just renaming the `/Developer` directory sufficient?  Will that break stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locate the 'Xcode Install' package. Show package contents. Inside the Resources folder you will find Xcode.mpkg. Install as usual.

Comment: How did you show package contents? I can't do that with OSLion

Comment: Right-click->"Show Package Contents"

Comment: Show Package Contents Doesn't show up for this package, I read that it doesn't show up on OS Lion

Comment: I just right-clicked on "Install Xcode.app" in my /Applications folder, and "Show Package Contents" was an option.

Answer (score 1):

renaming the folder should be enough but, yes, it may break stuff if you continue to use xcode 3. “it may” because you will still have a “/Developer” folder which will contain tools xcode use. if they (the tools) don't change too much between xc3 & 4, you shouldn't have any problem.

but stick with xcode4 and you won't have any problem at all.

Comment: "but stick with xcode4 and you won't have any problem at all." [citation needed]

Comment: I'm looking for an external link to documentation that specifies that a rename is sufficient.

Comment: sorry, I don't have any documentation or link to prove my answer true, just my own experience. is there any reason for you not be able to try the switch ? everything inside /Developer should be apple only. In my company, we do add some SDK into the PrivateFrameworks folders. We did it with Xcode 4 on 5 macs (MBP & iMac) without issues.

Comment: I've installed it, but when the next version comes out, I'd like to know the safest way to keep xcode4.1 safe.

Comment: you can install Developer tools outside /Developers. Right now, I have a /Developer and /Developer4_2 on my hard drive. I use the two versions of Xcode (but not at the same time) without problem.